ERRORES DE COMPILACIÓN PARA PROGRAMA ORIENTADO A OBJETOS EN JAVA
Tengo un problema con unos errores que se deben a problemas de duplicación de clases y estructura de archivos en Java.
El primer error indica que la clase Tienda, debe estar declarada en su propio archivo llamado Tienda.java.
Los siguientes errores indican que hay clases duplicadas en múltiples archivos:
Clase Tienda duplicada
Clase Usuario duplicada
Clase Controlador duplicada
Clase Vista duplicada
class Vista {
    private Controlador controlador;

    public Vista(Controlador controlador) {
        this.controlador = controlador;
    }

    public void mostrarMenuPrincipal() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Bienvenido a la Tienda");
        System.out.println("1. Iniciar Sesión");
        System.out.println("2. Crear Usuario");
        System.out.print("Selecciona una opción: ");
        int opcion = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); // Consumir salto de línea

        if (opcion == 1) {
            iniciarSesion();
        } else if (opcion == 2) {
            crearUsuario();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Opción no válida.");
        }
    }

    private void iniciarSesion() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Nombre de Usuario: ");
        String usuario = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Contraseña: ");
        String password = scanner.nextLine();

        if (controlador.validarUsuario(usuario, password)) {
            System.out.println("Inicio de sesión exitoso.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");
        }
    }

    private void crearUsuario() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Nombre de Usuario: ");
        String nombreUsuario = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Contraseña: ");
        String contraseña = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Correo Electrónico: ");
        String correo = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Entidad Federativa: ");
        String entidad = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Teléfono: ");
        String telefono = scanner.nextLine();    
        controlador.guardarUsuario(new Usuario(nombreUsuario, contraseña, correo, entidad, telefono));
        System.out.println("Usuario creado exitosamente.");
    }
}


Cada clase (Vista) debe ir en su propio archivo (Vista.java). Cuando necesitas ocupara la clase Vista en otro código, la importas con import Vista.

Hola Michael, bienvenido, podrías editar tu pregunta, y agregar, el arbol de directorios de tu proyecto?, con respecto a el nombre del archivo Vista, tienes dos posibilidades, o cambias el nombre del archivo o el de la clase, tienen que coincidir (salvo la extensión), si tienes más de una clase con determinado nombre, debes renombrar alguna, ya que de lo contrario, no se compila.
